# A-Frame AR change webcam viewport size (when i tried to change heigth and width, goes back)

Tags: size, webcam, aframe, ar.js

I used jquery to try and size the video component that it generated from the a-scene, and it changes the value from the  component, but i think that ar.js is triggering on resize event to ajust back to the window size.
I've tried to change the arjs attribute but nothing happens.

```
let videoComponent = $("video");
videoComponent.height(300);
videoComponent.width(300);

<a-scene embedded arjs='sourceType: webcam; sourceWidth: 600; sourceHeight: 400; displayWidth: 600; displayHeight: 400; canvasWidth: 600; canvasHeight: 400; debugUIEnabled: false;' >
```

Is there a way to set a fixed size, instead of having it full screen/window sized?

Answer (score 0):

It is an open bug of AR.js. I commented and labeled it as a bug (maybe the original issue has been lost).

https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/issues/750

Comment: I was the one to make that issue, but thanks, it would be very helpfull if that got fixed!